# How to update partial view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to update partial view product_images.html.erb through ajax
My js code is

```
    $("#delete-img").click(function(e){
      var checkValues = $('input[name=image_id]:checked').map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
      }).get();
      var id = $("#product_id").val();
      if(checkValues.length == 0) {
          alert("Select checkboxe first");
      }
      else{
          $.ajax({
              url: '/products/delete_product_images',
              type: 'delete',
              data: { ids: checkValues, id: id },
              success:function(data){
                  $('.product_images_class').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sproduct_images')%>");
              }
          });
      }

  });
```

But instead of updation it write `<%= escape_javascript(render 'product_images')%>` in that class after success.
Is there any another way?

Comment: This may help you [change a partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141509/onchange-display-change-a-partial).

Comment: that's not helping in my case

Comment: You can also try by giving partials folder name "<%= escape_javascript(render 'sproducts/sproduct_images')%>". if your partial and html.erb file which having ajax in different folders.

Comment: If your ajax call in html.erb file in script tag then it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling *server* code in the front-end view.

---

**JS**

When you call Ajax, you're basically using front-end JS to send an asynchronous request to your back-end Rails architecture.

This means that anything you do in your front-end Ajax *has* to use what's on the screen, or what's been sent back in the server response.

What you're doing is *mixing* the front-end ajax (IE `$.ajax`) with the back-end `ERB` functionality of `$('.product_images_class').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sproduct_images')%>");`

There are two ways around it:

---

**1. Call Server-Side JS**

The first fix would be to use the [`respond_to` functionality of Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to):

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js #-> invokes app/views/products/destroy.js.erb
      end
   end
end
```

This will effectively replace your `success` callback in your front-end ajax:

```
#app/views/products/destroy.js.erb
$('.product_images_class').html("<%=j render "product_images" %>");

 #Front-end codr
 $.ajax({
          url: '/products/delete_product_images',
          type: 'delete',
          data: { ids: checkValues, id: id }
 });
```

--

**2. Send the partial through to your front-end Ajax**

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
      if request.xhr? render "sproduct_images", layout: false
   end
end

#Front-end code
 $.ajax({
          url: '/products/delete_product_images',
          type: 'delete',
          data: { ids: checkValues, id: id },
          success: function(data) {
             $('.product_images_class').html(data);
          }
 });
```

Comment: It works. I just want to what is the purpose of layout: false
What it does?

Comment: If you render a view/partial, it will likely render the layout. Setting layout to false makes it so only the partial is rendered

Answer (score 0):

you are just trying to render the partial in the javascript.
You should look inside the data parameter passed in the success function  like this:

```
     success:function(data){
        $('.product_images_class').html(data);
     }
```