# Render partial after change select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views, onchange, partial

I have the following view

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %> <br><br>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %><br><br>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :survey_sections do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Abschnittsbeschreibung" %><br>
    <%= builder.fields_for :questions do |quest| %>
      <%= quest.text_field :text, :placeholder => "Frage" %> <br>
      <%= quest.fields_for :answers do |ans| %>
        <%= ans.text_field :text, :placeholder => "Antwort" %> <br>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
    <%= select_tag("question_type",options_for_select([["Radio", "radio"],["Checkbox", "check"]])) %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to render a partial in this view after selecting one of the options.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is render the partial with `display:none`

```
<div id='foo' style='display:none'>
  <%= render :foobar %>
</div>
```

And when a user select something, show it by JS(jQuery).

```
$('[name=question_type]').change(function() {
  $('#foo').show();
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this in a form, because the inputs in the hidden div will **still** be passed as parameters when the form is submitted. It is much better to load/remove/replace the contents of the div within the `change` event handler (rather than show/hide).

Comment: Hidden `input` tag values will be passed but just `div`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then try this:

**VIEW**

```
<%= select_tag("qustion_type",options_for_select([["Radio", "radio", {:onclick => "someFunction(#{controller_path})"}],["Checkbox", "check", {:onclick => "someFunction(#{controller_path})"}]])) %>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function someFunction(url) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {some_data: "data_value"},
    success: function(data) {
      //data has the html code that you render in controller
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT** (See Comments)

As you asked that you need to render a partial on each option select. So, for each option select you need to hit a controller method. In my example `url` is that controller end point(eg:- **render_radio_some_controller_path**).

```
def render_radio
  render :partial => "radio"
end
```

After this, it will go to the success block of Ajax call and **data** will have the html defined in `radio.html.erb`. Now, you just have to use `jQuery` to update the desired div html with **data**(Eg:- `jQuery("#some_div").html(data);`)

Comment: Could you explain me what i have to write in the controller that i can render _radio.html.erb file? Or which data i have to pass the variable data?

Comment: I don't know what iam doing wrong.i have the
 function someFunction(url){     jQuery.ajax({url: url, data: {some_data: "data_value"}, success: function(data) { jQuery("#some_div").html(data); } }); } 

it doesn't work and i dont know why :(

Comment: Then rob, it's really hard to tell you what's wrong until I see the error logs.

Comment: could you may tell me an tutorial or something like this which explain a solution for my problem?

Comment: Seems like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11142247/2968762) post says the exact same thing I'm trying to explain. Just don't go for hide/show option as it has performance issues. Go with ajax call solution.